# Andriod 9 patch Image is not displaying internal content

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-cardview, nine-patch

I have to create the custom card layout like this

[image]

So for that, I used an android 9 patch image but the internal small circle is not visible in the phones but it is visible inside the android layout editor.

Here is the image from the android Layout editor.

[image]

Here is the actual output on the phone.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why internal small icon is not visible on the actual phone?

Here is my card layout XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cv_custom"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="200dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
android:elevation="0dp"
app:cardElevation="0dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg_img"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/group_11"
        android:tint="#ff2624"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dog"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Animals"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/img"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/img"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="42dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.29" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you public ic_dog

Comment: What you mean?
I didn't understood!

Comment: It's android 9 patch image

Comment: @RohitSuthar he meant is it possible for you to share ic_dog image.

Comment: but ic_dog image is not 9 patch image.
It is just a simple image. The image which is in red color is 9 patch image

Comment: can you upload group_11 and ic_dog image so that i can observe what is the problem in you case. I do it my own its ok..